# Gold weight and carat based pricing

Tags: magento-community, catalog-price-rules, tierprice, pricing

I'm designing a jewelry site and I'd like gold weight/carat and diamond karat based pricing apart from base price (making/design charges) of the jewel.

The jewel price is completely decided based on how much it weighs and how much the diamond weighs. How do I set the pricing based on that

For example, a ring could have multiple customisation options like what purity of gold should it have (18k or 22k) or what kind of diamond to be used, based on diamond purity ranging from A to Z, diamond color from white to yellow. All these parameters decide the final price of the jewel.

Also I need to be able to update the gold per gram price on a day to day basis in the admin side so the price gets affect all over the site. The gold price may not be the same everyday, I want to able to give that flexibility to reduce prices when the prices fall. MANDATORY FEATURE

So there could be 3 grams of 22 carat gold or 5 grams of 18 carat gold. so 1 carat of 18k gold has so much percentage of gold and rest copper in it. How do I price these? I have option buttons for choosing category at the product page and I'd want the pricing to change as they are customizing their jewels.

Comment: Can you reword your question it isnt very clear.

Comment: Edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Perfect! Much clearer!

Comment: There is a plugin which almost achieves what I want. It's called jewelry product configurator. But I want some more customisations so I want to know if this can be done without that. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom options. These allow you to add an extra surcharge to a standard base price of a product. Each type of material would have a custom option with 1 unit which defines the price. As the customer adds more 'units' (carats for example) it will raise the price of the final product to be purchased and will add the chosen configuration to the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this with ChatGPT. You might need to use an API to get the live gold pricing instead of having to enter it manually. I created a simple calculator which I shared here https://github.com/thealloymarket/gold-value-calculator/ which was a stripped down version of a gold calculator I am building for https://thealloymarket.com/

You can see an example of a live pricing on the homepage and the API that I am using is https://metalpriceapi.com/

Comment: You can do all *what* with ChatGPT? I don't think it can customize your website for you. If it does, please explain how the chatbot is able to do this. Also, the question is about how to customize the website, not how to dynamically get the price of gold.